# Advantages/Disadvantages of Compiling as Both C and C++?

Tags: c++, c

So I've seen some C libraries written so that they compile without any changes with a C++ compiler, for example Lua.

What are some advantages and disadvantages of doing this?

A few basic ones I see are:

Advantages:

- library can be used with any C *or* C++ project with no extra effort (without using `extern "C"` for example).

Disadvantages:

- Harder to maintain because you need it compile as both (involves things like extra casts which can hide bugs)
- Either limit yourself to C/C++ (sacrificing things like flexible array members), or end up with non-standard C++.

But I'm sure there's more to consider than just the above advantages and disadvantages. What sort of cases would doing this be appropriate, instead of using either pure C or C++ for the library?

Comment: *// Harder to maintain because you need it compile as both //* is why open-source organizations usually have a well-maintained and well-resourced build farm to test each code change on a diverse collection of build environments, compilers and versions. The other disadvantages and concerns are all valid.

Comment: @rwong I'm not saying you shouldn't test it in various environments etc. I more meant you have to do extra work in your code to compile it as both (adding extra casts that you wouldn't need in C for example).

Answer (score 10):

Well, there are many disadvantages:

1. You cannot write good, idiomatic C, as it must also be valid C++.
2. Dito for C++, but worse.
3. Maintainers need to know C, and all the differences to C++. That is in effect a different third composite-language featuring the disadvantages of either plus all incompatibilities.
   I wonder if there is any good documentation for that? Especially as every combination of C version and C++ version is a different challenge.
4. If you use multiple languages, you have to compile it as C and include it within a manually added `extern "C"`-block anyway.

Why not simply write it in whatever language you want, featuring a C-interface, and optionally adding a C++ facade on top of it for ease of use?

Comment: http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B do a pretty good job of covering the differences. Note that most compilers will support basically all C features as an extension when compiling with C++ (which makes C++ _almost_ a superset of C when compiling with these compilers).

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Yes, [david tribble's text](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm) seems quite good for listing differences between C99 and C++98. But while the first is still often used, the two decades really make a difference for C++. The wikipedia text even on cursory reading seems a bit biased in favor of C++ and plain incorrect in many important points.

Comment: Is there really much difference between "idiomatic C" and "idiomatic C modified just enough to make it also valid C++"? Casting the result of `malloc` is one.

Comment: How does writing in idiomatic C and then writing a C++ wrapper to contain the weirdness (or vice versa) stack up?

Comment: @immibis you lose things like flexible array members and designated initializers, which are very very important for writing idiomatic C. It's not just the casts.

Comment: @DanNeely good question.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso designated initializers will make it into C++20 (although restricted compared to C).

Comment: C libraries tend to use macros "to a fuller extent" to overcome the significant disadvantages listed in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

A major advantage:

The authors only have to support one version of the code

Comment: This is possible when compiling exclusively as C or C++; some work may need to be done to support wrappers, but it is definitely still “one version of the code.”

Answer (score 1):

The point is - why would anyone do it?

This is a lot of effort for what would ultimately be hard to maintain code which is not good C or C++.

Point in case: error conditions. C++ uses exceptions while C does not support them.

Write a C library, add an ifdefed `extern "C"` in the header and that's it. Add a separate C++ wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

> What sort of cases would doing this be appropriate, instead of using either pure C or C++ for the library?

When you expect that there will be

- users of your library
- on a platform that doesn't have both a C compiler and a C++ compiler, which each produce object files compatible with the other
- wishing to write programs using the language you didn't.

Otherwise you should give C to C compilers, and C++ to C++ compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Advantages compared to what?

You can compare it to "write a C library". Assume you have a library that is written in C, without care for C++.

You can just run it through a C++ compiler. You'll have to make a few changes, if you happened to name a variable "class" or "template". You'll have to make a few more changes because type checking may be stricter in C++. You may have to make a few casts for the results of malloc or the arguments to free. The last item, some people will tell you it's not idiomatic C - because it might hide the fact that you missed including some header file. That's not a valid fear today.

I think all in all it will make your code better, at quite little cost.

Comment: I think you overestimate the compatibility of C and C++. You have to add a cast for every malloc, and you lose very nice C features like flexible array members and designated initializers. The stricter type checking is of course much nicer in a lot of cases (such as with enums), but most people turn on stricter type checking when writing pure C anyways.